# XSS Prevention in Python Flask Restful API

Tags: rest, security, flask, xss

I have written RESTful API's in Flask.
I won't be using templates/Jinja2.
Frontend is in angular.
In this case How should I prevent XSS attack.

Answer (score 2):

If the content-type of your responses is `application/json`, then it's not vulnerable to XSS, because no modern browser (from the past 5-10 years at least) will run javascript from a json response. However, you still need to protect the Angular app from XSS (which is basically not very difficult, it will *mostly* just be ok, but there are caveats, like for example using `*-unsafe-*` or links with user-supplied href, or constructing html directly by concatenating structure and data - it does happen sometimes).

Also while not XSS, consider json injection attacks, most of which will likely be prevented automatically, but constructing a json response in a non-standard way might allow an injection attack. Whatever data gets written into json must be appropriately encoded (done automatically by well-known json libs).